# Boundary value of continuous representative of a Sobolev function

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $f \in H^1(a,b)$, where $a<b$.

Then there exists a continuous representative $\tilde{f}(x) = \int_a^x f'(x) \ dx + c $ where $f'\in L^2(a,b)$ is the weak derivative of $f$ and c is a constant.

My question mainly regards that integration constant.

By the equality above it follows that $\tilde{f}(a) = c$.

Now I have read the assertion that for $\phi \in C^{\infty}_c(a,b)$ with $\int_a^b \phi \ dx = 1$ the following equation holds:

$\int_a^b f(x) \phi(x) \ dx = \tilde{f}(a) = c$

In this case $\phi$ seems to behave in the way of the dirac distribution, but I fail to say why that equality should hold.

Edit:

I have no formal source for this. It came up in a proof regarding the $H^1$ continuity of the "boundary operator":

$\rho(f) = (\ \int_a^b f(x) \phi(x) \ dx, \ \int_a^b f'(x) \ dx + \int_a^b f(x) \phi(x) \ dx ) \stackrel{!}{=} (\tilde{f}(a),\tilde{f}(b))$

which was then also subsequently used to derive:

$f \in H^1_0 \iff \rho(f) = (0,0)$

I found that proof quite intriguing, but I have not found it or a variation of it in any sources I looked up.

Comment: Do you have a source for the assertion?

Comment: You didn't ask a question. Are you looking for a proof of the assertion? You won't find one - it is obviously false.